# How can I calculate the expected ranking of a competitor from the probabilities of each competitor reaching first place?

Tags: pr.probability

Say I have several competitors contending over some prize.  I know the probabilities that any particular one of them will win the prize.  It is assumed that the competitors all want to achieve the highest ranking even if there is little chance of them winning.  It is assumed that all competitors apply a constant level of effort in order to get the highest ranking.  No tactics, strategy or interplay are involved.  How can I work out the expected ranking of a competitor from the probabilities?

For example, say 4 competitors have probabilities 0.5, 0.2, 0.2 and 0.1 of winning.  Then the expected ranking of the first is probably between 1 and 2 (that's a guess) but how do I find out for sure?

Comment: Don't you need to say a little more about how the rankings are determined, and what those probabilities are? Otherwise, it seems you can't say much at all about it. For example, perhaps one person's probability of winning is what it is because in effect they have to make a strategic gamble, with the result that they win if it pays off, but otherwise take last place. Such a person would have no chance of taking 2nd or 3rd, but you couldn't tell this just from the probability-of-winning information.

Comment: Thanks Joel - I've added some more detail which I hope covers your concerns.

Comment: I still don't think the question is well defined. Suppose we have three competitors that are all equally likely to win. That could describe many circumstances: It could be that all six orderings are equally likely, in which case everyone has expected rank 2. It could also be that the competitors always rank as ABC, BAC or CBA, in which case (A,B,C) have expected ranks (2,5/3,7/3). How does you data distinguish these cases?

Comment: David - in that case I would expect the answer to be 2 for each.

Comment: Let us call the competitors in your example Alice, Bob, Charles, and Diane.  

Are you saying that if we run the competition over and over, about 1/2 of the time Alice exerts more effort than the other three, about 1/5 of the time Bob exerts more effort than the other three competitors (and similarly Charles), and that 1/10 of the time Diane works the hardest?  

Are you also saying that this is the only information we have? If so, then it isn't enough information to say what the expected place for any competitor is. For all we know, Alice might exert no effort half the time.

Comment: On the other hand, if their placement has nothing to do with their effort, then David's answer obtains.

Comment: Pace - if we run the competition over and over, Alice will win half the time.  If she doesn't win but Bob does, can't we at least say that she is more likely to come second than Charles or Diane?

Comment: Not without further information.  It seems like you want it both ways.  On the one hand they win according to their effort, and their efforts are consistent.  On the other hand, their efforts are not consistent because their placements are not consistent.

If placement is not a function of effort, then placement after 1st place is arbitrary.

If placement is a function of effort, we need to know more about how the efforts of the individuals are behaving.

----

But to try and rephrase your question: maybe you want some sort of linear relationship among the efforts?

Comment: This question reminds me of a recent dispute I had with my son's 2nd grade math book publisher. He brought home a bar graph showing the number of children listing various activities as their "most favorite" hobbies (reading, swimming, etc.). But the exercises asked him to deduce the least favorite hobby or relative preferences, which of course you can't tell. My son pointed out that the least favorite hobby was probably something like cactus climbing, which wasn't even listed. Even though swimming was the most common most favorite, we calculated that it could also be the most disliked!

Comment: I think maybe I've confused things by using the expression "constant effort".  I was just trying to exclude the idea that competitors would slack off if they thought they couldn't get first place.  Regardless of this, what information about the competitors would be sufficient to arrive at a number for their expected ranking?

Comment: The simplest model I can think of (if you want to disallow ties) is that each competitor's performance is uniformly distributed in [0, M] where M is some upper bound which depends on the competitor.  From this you should be able to calculate values of M for each competitor which replicate the 1st-place probabilities above and then the problem is actually solvable.

Comment: Of course, it's likely that this model doesn't simulate all possible sets of probabilities of winning first place.  For example, it cannot simulate the situation where one competitor always wins unless the values of M for all but one competitor is zero!  I haven't really thought about it, but it's also possible that more than one set of values of M can correspond to the same set of probabilities of winning first place.

Comment: @Qiaochu: of course, there are many other possible models that can be chosen (resulting in different answers) and the question of which is most appropriate is not a mathematical one.

Comment: I want to echo Reid's point. For example, I would have thought Gaussians were much more reasonable then uniform probabilities. Ultimately, this is an empirical question about how a competitor's performance varies from day to day, and there is no reason to think the answer will be the same in every form of competition.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common problem in the analysis of poker tournaments, particularly at the final table. Because there are prizes for second and lower places, to calculate your expected prize money, you would like a reasonable function from the distribution of chips to your place distribution.

Of course, mathematically, **this problem is underdetermined**. So, you need to make more assumptions.

The usual model used by professional poker players who specialize in single table tournaments, where this is most important, is the *Independent Chip Model* (ICM). The ICM is commonly described in a few different ways. One is that the chips of the players are independently removed from the table one by one, and a players is eliminated when his last chip is eliminated. Another is that the winner is chosen with probability in proportion with his share of the chips, then his chips are removed, and you recursively determine the second place finisher, etc. It may not be obvious that these are equivalent, since the latter can easily be extended to non-integer chip counts and makes it obvious that doubling the number of chips for everyone does not change the finishing probabilities. However, they are equivalent since you can shuffle the chips and rank players by their highest chips. Revealing the shuffle from the bottom gives you the first interpretation. Revealing the shuffle from the top gives you the second.

For example, with stacks of 5, 2, 2, and 1, the ICM says that the chip leader finishes

- 1st: 0.5000
- 2nd: 0.3056
- 3rd: 0.1508
- 4th: 0.0437

You can download a free advanced ICM calculator I wrote called [ICM Explorer](http://www.icmexplorer.com/), which performs the calculations for tournaments of up to 10 players, and tells you how much equity you need to call, bluff, or semibluff. For example, you might be considering risking 3000 chips to gain 4000, but the equity you might need against your opponent's range might be 55%, since you might lose more equity when you lose than you get when you win.

An alternative model considered by Thomas Ferguson is [diffusion](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/papers/unpublished/gamblersruin.pdf). This might be a more realistic model under some circumstances, as chips move from player to player instead of being removed from the table. It may be a better model for poker tournaments with a limit betting structure instead of no limit, since in the latter it is possible for the second stack to be eliminated in one hand. However, this model has not found favor among poker players because it's much harder to calculate. Nevertheless, there have been some efforts to compare the ICM, diffusion, and empirical data.

A drawback of the ICM is that players might predictably gain equity or lose equity in the course of a hand, while tournament equity (and all place probabilities) ought to be a martingale. You can see this according to a [Nash equilibrium calculator](http://www.holdemresources.net/hr/sngs/icmcalculator.html?action=calculate&bb=200&sb=100&ante=0&structure=0.5,0.3,0.2&s1=3000&s2=2000&s3=1000&s4=&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=&s9=) for push/fold play. With stacks of 3000, 2000, and 1000, and a 50-30-20 prize structure, if you average over all permutations, the player with 3000 chips averages a slight gain in equity, and in general the chip leader gains slightly since players are the most risk-averse against the chip leader. There are at least three groups of people trying to come up with a better model. In the mean time, the ICM with slight adjustments is what serious single table tournament players use.

Poker servers have expressed interest in using the Independent Chip Model to settle poker tournaments interrupted by crashes. It's not easy to calculate the ICM for several thousand players. The naive algorithms for n players use about n! calculations, although faster computations are possible. As far as I know, poker servers only use it to suggest possible deals at the final table.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ are your competitors.  You are only given the information Probability($A_i$ beats all other $A_j$) for each $i$.  There are examples above, where this information is not enough to determine how the competition finishes.  For another example, suppose that one of the competitors *always* takes first place.  So, one of the given probabilities is 1, and all the others are 0.  What does that tell you about the interactions among the losers?  Absolutely nothing.